# Почему округляются значения при делении одного агрегированного числа на другое в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Почему округляются значения при делении одного агрегированного числа на другое в PostgreSQL:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT X) FILTER (WHERE Y IS NOT NULL) :: numeric / COUNT(DISTINCT X)
```

Вместо долей вижу просто 1

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А почему Вы не приводите второй операнд к numeric?

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример из create table, insert нескольких строк и select запроса с неверным результатом. Мне воспроизвести не удалось, оператор деления numeric на bigint возвращает numeric

Comment: Может быть просто данные такие? [Например](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/35824)